# when view that not display complete,set it gone

Tags: android, android-layout

There is a horizontal LinearLayout ,there are some TextView int he LinearLayout. some TextView is Gone or Visibile depends on data 
The text in the TextView is not fixed. when text is too long. it will show partial. 
some TextView is Gone or Visibile depends on data 
For example

```
the 1st TextView is  "qwerty", it width is 100dp  
the 2st TextView is  "qwerty", it width is 100dp 
the 3st TextView is  "qwerty", it width is 100dp 
the 4st TextView is  "qwerty", it width is 100dp 
the LinearLayout's width is 280dp
```

so hide the 3st TextView and the 4st TextView.

the LinearLayout in the RecyclerView, so can not remove the child, because the child will reuse in other item.and can not need too much time to measure the width in case of junk when scrolling fast.

Answer (score 0):

you can make it scroll horzontial
or give weight sum to linear layout = 2 and for the 2 texts give weight = 1 and width = 0dp and height wrap_content